# Why can't I replace string for this symbol in DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

In my dataframe I have string which are enclosed with this symbol below, for example:

```
《very good》
```

I have to replace it with empty string, as below, but it didn't work:

```
df.replace(['《', '》'], ['', ''], inplace=True)
```

Anything I did wrong? I may be due to the symbol '《' & '》'? How to deal with this?

Comment: You missed the argument regex = True, df.replace(['《', '》'], ['', ''], regex = True, inplace = True)

Comment: @Vaishali. You are right and thanks so much!!!